# Implementing interface but returning a subclass of the return type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting

I am working with ASP.NET MVC in C#. I am creating service classes. I have a service interface for Driver service interfaces (IDriverService).

It has the following method definition:

```
Driver New();
```

I have two implementations of this interface which implements this method as such:

```
Driver New()
{
   return new Driver();
}

Driver New()
{
   return new SubclassOfDriver();
}
```

As you can see one implementation implements the New method by returning a base Driver, and the other is for some subclass of Driver.

The problem is by implementing the interface I have to return a 'Driver' but sometimes I want to return a 'SubclassOfDriver'. I could say that you should cast the result to the Driver you want but this is unsafe and the coder would require information about the implementation to acertain which Driver has been instantiated. What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You could return the Interface instead of the Class (so `IDriver New();`)

Comment: Casting to a base-class is not unsafe and not even necessary. It's an implicit safe conversion.

Comment: The client shouldn't care which `Driver` was instantiated - it's a design smell if he does.

Comment: @Frammo once you get an instance of Driver, why do you want to cast it back to SubclassOfDriver?

Answer (score 7):

You can effectively overload the return type using explicit interface implementation:

```
Driver IDriverService.New()
{
   return New(); // Calls the method below
}

public SubclassOfDriver New()
{
   return new SubclassOfDriver();
}
```

Now any code which only knows about your implementation *as* an implementation of the interface will see the explicit interface implementation method, and just expect a return type of `Driver`.

Any code which refers to the service via its concrete type will only see the *second* method, and expect a return type of `SubclassOfDriver`. For example:

```
SpecialFactory specialFactory = new SpecialFactory();
SubclassOfDriver subclassDriver = specialFactory.New(); // Fine
IDriverFactory generalFactory = specialFactory;
IDriver generalDriver = generalFactory.New(); // Fine
// This wouldn't compile
SubclassOfDriver invalid = generalFactory.New();
```

Alternatively, you might want to make your interface generic:

```
public interface IDriverFactory<TDriver> where TDriver : Driver
{
    TDriver New();
}

public class SpecialDriverFactory : IDriverFactory<SubclassOfDriver>
{
    public SubclassOfDriver New()
    {
        return new SubclassOfDriver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics:

```
public class Driver { }
public class SubclassOfDriver : Driver { }

public interface IDriverService<T> where T : Driver
{
    T New();
}

public class SpecificService : IDriverService<Driver>
{
    public Driver New()
    {
        return ...;
    }
}

public class OtherSpecificService : IDriverService<SubclassOfDriver>
{
    public SubclassOfDriver New()
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is by implementing the interface I have to return a `Driver` but sometimes I want to return a `SubclassOfDriver`

The problem is not with returning a `Driver`, but with "sometimes wanting the return type to be `SubclassOfDriver`". If your code needs implementations of your `IDriverService` to return the derived type under some circumstances, you have picked the abstraction level that is wrong for your needs. The principle of hiding the implementation behind an interface (i.e. hiding the `SubclassOfDriver` behind `Driver`) is that you should never need to make calls specific to `SubclassOfDriver`.

One way of solving this is refactoring the `Driver` class to include the methods of `SubclassOfDriver` that are not available otherwise. You can make these methods optional, letting the callers test if a particular subclass implements them or not.

Answer (score 1):

`SubclassOfDriver` *is* a `Driver`.

There is nothing wrong with that.